# How to recover the flutter files?

Tags: file, flutter

I coded a flutter project and it worked well but after few days when I reopened it unfortunately all my project files are crashed and the code I wrote is replaced by some other code .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Sny.png)

Comment: Revert to the last commit with the code in question?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the the ( lib FOLDER ) > then local history > then show history ,
after that, choose which date you want to recover your files at , and then click on it and choose revert.

this way to recover all files of the lib folder, if you want to recover only code of a specific file , then you start with that file not the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Right click your File .in your case main.dart

Right Click ->Local History-> Show History

then you can revert your changes.

[image]